# Recursive angular directive with large data

Tags: angularjs

I have a angular directive to generate nested list structure. However when i get large data, browser gets stuck & is very slow. If it was only ng-repeat i could have used limitTo but this is a recursive template. Any suggestion please.

http://jsfiddle.net/L97o5swa/14/

```
treeModule.directive('tmTree', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E', // tells Angular to apply this to only html tag that is <tree>
    replace: true, // tells Angular to replace <tree> by the whole template
    scope: {
      t: '=src',
      fetchChildren: '&fetchChildren',
      selectNode : '&selectNode' // create an isolated scope variable 't' and pass 'src' to it.  

    },    
    controller : function($scope){
      console.log('aaa');

    },
      template: '<ul><branch ng-repeat="c in t.children" src="c" fetch-children="fetchChildren()" select-Node="selectNode({node :child})"   ng-class="c.expandChildren ? \'\':\'collapsed\' "></branch></ul>' ,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

    }   
  };
});

treeModule.directive('branch', function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E', // tells Angular to apply this to only html tag that is <branch>
    replace: true, // tells Angular to replace <branch> by the whole template
    scope: {
      b: '=src',
      fetchChildren: '&fetchChildren', // create an isolated scope variable 'b' and pass 'src' to it.  
      selectNode : '&selectNode'
    },
    controller : function($scope,$element){

    } ,   
      template: '<li class="treeNode"><div class="wholerow"></div><span id="chevron-right" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" ></span><a ng-click="selectNode({child : b})">{{ b.text }}</a></li>',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      //// Check if there are any children, otherwise we'll have infinite execution

      var has_children = angular.isArray(scope.b.children);
      var parent = scope.b;
      //// Manipulate HTML in DOM
      if (has_children) {        
          element.append($compile( '<tm-tree src="b" fetch-children="fetchChildren()" select-Node="selectNode({node:child})" ></tm-tree>')(scope) );

        // recompile Angular because of manual appending
        //$compile(element.contents())(scope); 
      }
      var chevronRight = angular.element(element.children()[1]);

      chevronRight.on('click',function(event) {
         event.stopPropagation();
         chevronRight.toggleClass('glyphicon-chevron-right');
         chevronRight.toggleClass('glyphicon-chevron-down');
        if(has_children){
          element.toggleClass('collapsed');
            if(scope.b.children.length == 0) {

        }
      }
    });     
    }
  };

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell based on the piece of code you posted. But my initial instinct is that you shouldn't be using so many jqLite references like element and append. You should handle more of this functionality within the template itself using ngRepeat (ie. `if (has_children) { element.append...`) and ngClick (ie. `chevronRight.on('click'...`). jqLite operations are expensive.